# DataContract framework not working when serializing objects to JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, datacontract

Here is my model:

```
namespace RESTalm
{
    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(Entity))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Field))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Value))]
    public class Entities
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public List<Entity> entities;

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public int TotalResults;
    }

    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(Field))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Value))]
    public class Entity
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public Field[] Fields;

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public String Type;
    }

    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(Value))]
    public class Field
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public String Name;

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public Value[] values;
    }

    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(Value))]
    public class Value
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public String value;
    }    
}
```

Here is my program:

```
        private String toJSON(Object poco)
        {
            String json;
            DataContractJsonSerializer jsonParser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(poco.GetType());
            MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream();

            jsonParser.WriteObject(buffer, poco);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(buffer);
            json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            buffer.Close();

            return json;
    }
```

When the object `jsonParser` initializes it doesn't seem to recognize my model at all.
This leads to an empty `MemoryStream()`.
Please help.

P.S. I have cut-out exception-handling in my program because it's distracting. Thanks.
Also, for the moment the object `poco` is always assumed to be a type in my model.

Comment: And yes; they are all in the same name-space and have all the needed references.

Comment: It looks like you need to rewind the stream to the beginning by resetting its [`Position`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.position.aspx) before you can read from it.

Comment: @dbc you genious, i love you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewind the stream to the beginning by resetting its [`Position`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.position.aspx) before you can read from it, for instance like so:

```
public static string ToJson<T>(T obj, DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = null)
{
    serializer = serializer ?? new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj == null ? typeof(T) : obj.GetType());
    using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(memory, obj);
        memory.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(memory))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```